# Issue in tokeninput when we hit space bar

Tags: javascript, ajax, token, jquery-tokeninput

If I hit space bar then the tokeninput.js hits ajax with empty query string, what to do please help.

```html
<div class="text-field">
  <input type="text" id="tags" name="tag" />
</div>
```

```js
$("#tags").tokenInput(baseUrl + 'tags-for-course', {
  prePopulate: tags,
  hintText: "Type in a search term",
  searchDelay: 300,
  minChars: 3,
  preventDuplicates: true,
  zindex: 9999,
  theme: "facebook",
  onResult: function(item) {
    return item;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set "2" use "minChars" setting of tokenInput. so something like

```
{
    prePopulate: tags,
    hintText: "Type in a search term",
    searchDelay: 300,
    minChars: 2,
    preventDuplicates: true,
    zindex: 9999,
    minChars: 2
    theme: "facebook",
    onResult: function (item) {
        return item;

    }
}
```

Comment: I have already used it as "3", but I want it should not include empty spaces